# Lebesgue Measure of the Image of an Interval

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, derivatives, lebesgue-measure

Given that $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is an arbitrary function, I'm looking for what can be said about the size of an interval $I$ under $f$.

If we define $D := \{x \in \mathbb{R} : f \text{ is differentiable at } x\}$ and take a point $d \in D$, then since $|f'(d)|$ acts like a local scale factor of $f$ around $d$, it seems reasonable to expect that:

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\mu^*(f[I_{d,h}])}{2h} = |f'(d)|$$

where $\mu^*$ denotes Lebesgue outer measure, $I_{d,h} := (d-h,d+h)$, and if $A$ is some set then $f[A]$ denotes the image of $A$ under $f$.

---

Unfortunately (as usual) mathematics is not so straightforward. Without too much effort, it follows by playing around with the definition of the derivative that:

$$\limsup_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\mu^*(f[I_{d,h}])}{2h} \leq |f'(d)|$$

and hence we get the desired equality above if $f'(d) = 0$.

But the more general result can fail in seemingly pathologically counterexamples. For example it's possible to construct a measurable function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q} \cup C$ (where $C$ is the Cantor set) which is differentiable on all of $C$, and $f'(x) = 1$ for all $x \in C$.

---

However this is a pretty pathologically example, and even then it only fails on a null set. So my conjecture is the following:

> Given that $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is an arbitrary function, and $D := \{x \in \mathbb{R} : f \text{ is differentiable at } x\}$. Then:
>
> $$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\mu^*(f[I_{d,h}])}{2h} = |f'(d)|$$
> for almost all $d \in D$.

---

**So Far**

If $f$ is a locally a Darboux function around $d$ (in other words: satisfies the intermediate value theorem in small enough intervals around $d$), then $f[I_{d,h}]$ is an interval for small enough $h$, and it can be shown that the equality holds at $d$.

Therefore the conjecture **is** true for Darboux functions (and functions which are locally Darboux around almost all points in $D$).

But what about the more general case?

Comment: $f[I]$ need not be measurable even if $f$ is. You might be interested in various differentiation results regarding Lebesgue measure. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem

Comment: @Mason Thank you. I am aware of the Lebesgue differentiation theorem (in fact I imagined this conjecture as a companion to it of sorts), but you are right that I completely overlooked that images might not be measurable. I have edited my question to use outer measure in case there's something of substance remaining in my conjecture.

Answer (score 0):

If $O, \Omega$ are open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $F \colon O \to \Omega$ is a homeomorphism that is differentiable at $x_0 \in O$, then
$$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\frac{m(F(B(x_0, \varepsilon)))}{m(B(x_0, \varepsilon))} = |\det(DF(x_0))|.$$
The proof can be found in "Measure Theory and Integration" by Michael Taylor on page 91. The proof that $\limsup_{\varepsilon \to 0}\frac{m(F(B(x_0, \varepsilon)))}{m(B(x_0, \varepsilon))} \leq |\det(DF(x_0))|$ is relatively straightforward. The proof for the $\liminf$ uses degree theory.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, and the reference. Unfortunately being a homeomorphism is a bit too strong of an assumption for me. The claim can already be proven by only assuming continuity of $F$ (in fact assuming the multi-dimensional version of Darboux is enough). I was looking for the more general case.